# Why char is unsigned and int is signed by default?

Tags: c++, gcc, char, range

I'm using gcc as my c++ compiler and when I declare a variable of int datatype then it is taken as signed by default. But in case of char it is taken as unsigned.
Why is that ?
Because in xcode IDE char is taken as signed by default.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   system("clear");
   int x;
   char y;
   cout<<INT_MIN<<" "<<INT_MAX<<endl;
   cout<<CHAR_MIN<<" "<<CHAR_MAX<<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
-2147483648 2147483647
0 255
```

Comment: The C++ Standard, like the C Standard, specifies plain `int` is the same type as `signed int`, but `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are three different types and it is implementation-defined whether `char` is signed or unsigned. This is all for the hysterical raisins - I mean historical reasons.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. `char` is *not* either signed or unsigned by default. It is a separate type from both of those, and it is up to the implementation whether that type behaves in a signed or unsigned manner. That said, "why" questions generally don't work on Stack Overflow - we can't read the minds of the people who made those decisions, and we don't take subjective questions.

Comment: We need to be more careful with the raisins. Them and Almonds are sucking California dry.

Comment: Use `-fsigned-char` compiler option to change this.  (But it is good to ensure your program works correctly regardless of this setting)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`char` is an unsigned type on your system, because the people who implemented your system chose that it should be unsigned. This choice varies between systems, and the C++ language specifies that either is allowed. You cannot assume one choice if you wish to write programs that work across different systems.

Note that `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are all three distinct types regardless of whether `char` is signed or not. By contrast, `int` and `signed int` are two names for one and the same type.

Comment: "*There is no "default" choice*" - funny, because Microsoft actually does [make the default type configurable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/j-default-char-type-is-unsigned?view=msvc-170).

Comment: Well if microsoft has a "default" and that you can change the default, is a pretty good proof that there is no default.

Comment: @JawadElFou  No.  It just means Microsoft specifies a "default" type, and allows that to be changed.   Microsoft don't determine what the standard requires, or doesn't.  And Microsoft has form (mostly well in the past now) for introducing non-standard features that conflict with the standard - and even documenting some of them as being standard.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I guess there is then 
¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Microsoft allows the **implementation** choice to be changed. The statement that the standard sets no default is absolutely correct.